# Exception：unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.realtech.flight.FlightStatus.speed() in kie-server container

Tags: java, drools, fusion, kie-workbench, kie-server

I am a new in drools, I am trying to execute a simple CEP rule on Drools kie server 6.4.0.Final running on Tomcat7, but I am getting following error when i try to start the kie container.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId com.realtech:stdout:1.0-SNAPSHOT was not in cache, checking classpath
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG KieModule Lookup. ReleaseId com.realtech:stdout:1.0-SNAPSHOT was not in cache, checking maven repository
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR Unable to build KieBaseModel:kbase1
Unable to Analyse Expression speed == 200:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.realtech.flight.FlightStatus.speed()]
[Near : {... speed == 200 ....}]
             ^
[Line: 15, Column: 4] : [Rule name='flight print']
```

My code is like:

FlightStatus.drl

```
package com.realtech.flight;
//import com.realtech.flight.FlightStatus;

declare FlightStatus
    @role(event)
end

rule "flight print"
no-loop true

when
    $flight : FlightStatus( speed == 200 ) // over window:time(1m)  
then
    System.out.println("test");     
end
```

FlightStatus.java

```
package com.realtech.flight;

/**
 * This class was automatically generated by the data modeler tool.
 */

public class FlightStatus implements java.io.Serializable
{

   static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public java.lang.Float speed;

   public FlightStatus()
   {
   }

   public java.lang.Float getSpeed()
   {
      return this.speed;
   }

   public void setSpeed(java.lang.Float speed)
   {
      this.speed = speed;
   }

   public FlightStatus(java.lang.Float speed)
   {
      this.speed = speed;
   }

}
```

knowledge base settings in kie-workbench:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMOVx.png)

and then I got the exception when start containter in kie-server.

But it's successful when I delete the declare:

```
declare FlightStatus
    @role(event)
end
```

or delete `speed == 200`.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Don't make `speed` public.

Comment: it's same result, i did try. thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. - You might try int (or double) instead of Float.

Comment: it's not ok by double, string, boolean or int.

Comment: My test scenario is:  one computer install drools-kie-wb  6.4.0.Final in tomcat7. and another computer install kie-server  6.4.0.Final in tomcat7.    At drools-kie-wb  edit rule and data object, build&deploy.  The Kie-server(6.4.0.Final) as a server template in drools-kie-wb ('Deploy->Rule Deployments'), and then click "add container" link and choose that jar and click finish.  Start the container by click "start" button.  Then  the kie-server tomcat log print the error "unable to resolve method using strict-mode".

Comment: If you look at this part of the error, `com.realtech.flight.FlightStatus.speed()`. It shows speed as a function and not a variable. I created a method, something like `public void speed() { return this.getSpeed()}`, specific to my implementation and it worked.